# Initializing the minValue and the maxValue and the display wont show. Also, display if no number was entered

Tags: java

If initialize the min and the max values to 0 it will keep on being the smallest value.I want it to show the largest number and the smallest number after the user has entered a series of integers. What would be a sensible value?

Also, it won't display **"You did not enter any numbers"** if the user has not entered any number.

my code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LargestAndSmallest 
{ 
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   { 

      int input; 

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

      System.out.print("Enter an integer number or -99 to quit: "); 
            input = keyboard.nextInt(); 

      int minValue = 1; 
      int maxValue; 

      while (input != -99) 
      { 
            if (input > maxValue) 
            { 
                 maxValue = input; 
            } 
            else if (input < minValue) 
            { 
                 minValue = input; 
            }

         System.out.print("Enter an integer number or -99 to quit: ");   
            input = keyboard.nextInt(); 
      }

      if (input == -99) 
      { 
         System.out.println("\nYou did not enter any numbers"); 

         System.out.print("\nLargest: " + maxValue); 

         System.out.print("\nSmallest:" + minValue);
      }  

 } 

}
```

Comment: I would have thought that `minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE` would be safe ranges to start them at...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize minValue and maxValue to the first number i.e. the value of `input` after the statement before the `while` loop executes:

```
input = keyboard.nextInt();
```

After that, if you find bigger or smaller nos. in the list, the largest and smallest nos. will get reflected as required

Comment: also need to remove "else" from "else if (input < minValue)" in case your input consists only from 1 number